# Flutter android - notification working in ios testflight does not work when downloaded from app store

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I published the "B&B Prosthetic Hair" application that I wrote with Flutter to the app store and google play, androşd receives notifications completely without any problems, it works in testflight and emulator on ios, but when you download it from the app store, the notification does not appear, and there is no notification permission in the settings. But testfliht also shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request access to the user if you are using Firebase Messaging.

You can read more [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/permissions#requesting-permissions).

Comment: But testflight works. Does it work in testflight without permission?

Comment: The Apple platforms require the request permission to external notifications therefore I don't know how it works in TestFlight without permission.